# Multi-tenancy DB & Proxy but seperate networks for web apps

Tags: docker, networking, docker-network

I'm trying to design a multi-tenant system as per the diagram below:

- one database, because the database uses a lot of memory
- one proxy web server, because the host only has one IP address
- isolated networks for customers' web applications - one network per customer, for some semblance of security
- multiple containers for each customer, because each customer will be running multiple web apps

as i understand docker, i can make separate networks so containers can't talk across networks, but in this case, i want the proxy web server to be able to connect to all web app containers, and all web app containers to be able to connect to the database.

- can i achieve this this with multiple networks?
- can the proxy container know the hostnames of web app containers created after the proxy container is created?

[image: servers]

Comment: Are you planning to run this all on a single host?  How do you plan to scale this to as few as a hundred customers?  Are you building a hosting service, or a complete application (do you or the customers control the web apps)?

Comment: @DavidMaze i was going to start on a single host to keep it simple.  if it grows to a point where more than one host is needed, then i'll hire someone more knowledgable.  building a hosting service with a small selection of web apps.